# Is Nietzsche 'power' neither value neutral nor practical?

Tags: nietzsche, metaethics

### Main question

Is Nietzsche 'power' neither value neutral nor practical?

### Subsidiaries that I considered in asking it

If so, how can it be demarcated from the object of philosophy, generally enough thought? So 'wisdom' or 'understanding' or 'truth'. As I just can't think of anything that is neither an action (practical) nor an assessment of value (and whatever is value neutral will deform judgments of value and their strength), but nevertheless informs both (to whosoever that embodies it), but is not the general object of philosophy ('truth' 'understanding' etc.).

Is Nietzsche's declamation about philosophy, "I am not a philosopher" "I am dynamite", less, then, about radicalizing its aims, than an expression of how much *Christian ethics* has deformed philosophy **hithertofore**.

Comment: How can a value be value neutral? And why should it be "demarcated from the object of philosophy" (what is that?), truth and wisdom are also seen as valuable. Beyond that I am unable to follow at all, but "neither action nor value" reminds me of [thick, a.k.a. value-laden, concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thick-ethical-concepts/). Nietzsche's decla*r*ation (?) is not about philosophy, but about himself. In his lifetime he was thought of more as a literary figure, it was Heidegger who turned him into a pillar of philosophy.

Comment: didn't say that, but i kinda see your point @Conifold . ps thanks, you sounds so unfriendly with your comments, but it's fine, i get them!

Comment: i think you *more or less* spotted the issue with this train of thought, though. just, if something is value neutral need not mean it is not a judgment of value. annoying, my thinking was skewed (i think?) @Conifold

Comment: edited something in, just not sure if i'm still making a basic logical (syllogistic) error @Conifold ? as to 'neither action nor value' i can't tell you what they mean if you won't apply them to your everyday life! shamefully, on my part

Comment: Are the questions, (1) how does power, as Nietzsche understands it, relate to value? (2) is the object of power also the object of philosophy?? and (3) what does Nietzsche ultimately mean by the statement "I am not a philosopher"?

Comment: yeah more or less, it can be broken down that way i mean @ClearMountainWay or just what is power?